# Jquery not reading when switching to landscape

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, resize

So I have a script doing a resize if the window width is < than 768.  I am trying it on an iphone which it should work.  My script:

```
$( window ).resize(function() 
{   
    if ($(window).width() <= 768) 
    {
        var platformHeight = $('#platform-mobile .platform-video video').height();
        $('#platform-mobile .platform-video').css('height', platformHeight + 'px');
        $('#platform-mobile .mejs-controls').css('bottom', '-' + platformHeight + 'px');
    }
})
```

I tried ending the script with .resize() in order to try calling it after the full resize fired and that didn't work.

Comment: So are you saying that the resize function is not getting executed when you turn your phone? Does this get executed after the page finishes loading?. Did you try outputting something before the if condition to make sure it gets into the .resize function?

Comment: It is executing I put in an alert which gets called telling the height of $('#platform-mobile .platform-video')

Comment: it always returns 150.  it the function seems to call when I swipe too.  Then I switch to landscape and it alerts 150 again then crashes (it does not crash if I don't have an alert)

Comment: I would need to see a demo to help you better.

Comment: https://beta2.globaledit.com/overview/

There is a video futher down.

The SSL doesn't work so it will present a warning since the SSL is set up for the production site.

Comment: I removed the alert due to the crashing it and always calling when swiped.

Comment: responsive.css is missing... not sure if it's important and thus why it's always giving you 150... just mentioning it in case...

Comment: On my android device, it's working well... I get a height of 303 in landscape and 194 in portrait. But on my iPod, I get the same values as you... always 150.

Comment: Just removed the responsive which was something existing on our their end originally (not sure if it exists in production).  I do notice this error not sure if this causes it The value "device-width;" for key "width" is invalid, and has been ignored. beta2.globaledit.com/:13
The value "1;" for key "initial-scale" was truncated to its numeric prefix.

Comment: Unrelated but the meta tags should be: `<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`

Comment: Oh, thanks.  If you don't mind me asking what is the MobileOptimzized for content 320 do.  and by the way thanks for your assistance with the initial issue too

Comment: Tells the mobile browser the screen width that the page has been optimized for. Not very effective for devices with different screen widths. In your case you might not need it.

Comment: Oh ok, yeah I think that part I will remove since this is being developed responsive.

Comment: As for the problem, I think I understand. On my Android, the video tag shows up correctly so the height:auto!important correctly resizes the video. On my iPod, a div shows up (because the video can't be played directly on the page)... not the actual video so a div does not adjust the height proportionally to the width. You need to make the calculations yourself according to the initial ratio.

Comment: Also pulling up on the ipad in portrait mode is pulling up at the wrong size initially too.  Could it be as a result of me doing the $(window).width() and it not recognizing that?

Comment: Oh, well damn.  that makes things more complicated.  well thanks for your assistance on that.  Didn't know the video tag wasn't supported in apple devices

Comment: As mentioned in my last comment, it's iOS that display's a div instead of a video tag. Plug your iOS device to your computer. Open Safari, and enable developer tools (google it), you will then be able to inspect the dom elements of the iOS device.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the tip.  Running on a windows box I don't know of any way to do this.  Everything I have seen online states I have to have mac OSX lion or higher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to continue from the comments

For iOS, you need to adjust the height of `.platform-video` like this:

```
$('.wp-video').width()/760 * 428
```

Where `$('.wp-video').width()` is the current video width divided by the original video width (in this case 760) multiplied by the original video height (428). So in the case of my iPod the height should be 243 (rounded).

Comment: This almost solved it.  The container is scaling properly now but still has some issues during the transitions.  Running on windows box I can't do inspect element for iphones to further test.

Comment: This did fix the height issue that I was having.  Found a way of targeting the video tag since it has an ID.  Thanks everyone for helping with the solution.